# Android OnEditorActionListener() actionId give 0 when I click Done

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard

I have created a keyboard. When the user enters numbers they're sent to a particular `EditText`, but when the user clicks on the "Done" key it doesn't go to `setOnEditorActionListener` (but it does close the keyboard).

This is my code:

```
 final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
    txtQty.setHeight(1);
    txtQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 42));
    txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    txtQty.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    txtQty.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    txtQty.setTextSize(9);
    txtQty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtQty.setHint("0.0");
    txtQty.setHighlightColor(R.color.green);
    tr.addView(txtQty);
    txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT ) { ......}
```

Here it gives `actionId = 0` and `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT = 5`

When I run through the Android soft keyboard its working fine.

```
  txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
            Log.i("---EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT---" , EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            Log.i("---actionId---" , actionId);
            Log.i("---event---" , event);
            Log.i("---EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE---" , EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Here it's giving `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT = 5, actionId = 5` and  `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE = 6, actionId = 6`

But when I run through my soft keyboard it gives `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT = 5, 
actionId = 0` and `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE = 6, actionId = 0`.

Why didn't it take the `actionId` value on my soft keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

if you wanna got the actionid try this way:

in my project i change the edittext's properties like that

```
input type  -----  text
ime options -----  actionDone
```

and in java file:

```
  etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
  etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorActionListener);

private OnEditorActionListener mEditorActionListener = new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                       //do something
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

in this way could got the actionid = 6;